# Converting A public key in SubjectPublicKeyInfo format to RSAPublicKey format java

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, pkcs#1

The PublicKey.getEncoded(), returns a byte array containing the public key in SubjectPublicKeyInfo (x.509) format, how do i convert it to RSA public key encoding?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use Bouncy Castle's [`SubjectPublicKeyInfo`](http://bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/asn1/x509/SubjectPublicKeyInfo.html), like this:

```
byte[] encoded = publicKey.getEncoded();
SubjectPublicKeyInfo subjectPublicKeyInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(
        ASN1Sequence.getInstance(encoded));
byte[] otherEncoded = subjectPublicKeyInfo.parsePublicKey().getEncoded();
```

Comment: This doesn't serve the pourpose. here we have just casted the public key into a RSAPublicKey object, but when i say RSAPublicKey.getEncoded(), i still get the key in x.509 format and not RSA format.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Your approach worked. I am posting the exact snippet i used.

Comment: The above comment from @AshishKumarShah seems incorrect; I do get a DER encoded key of course, but it does seem to be a PKCS#1 formatted key (ps Hi Martijn, hope everything is OK).

Comment: Hey Maarten. @AshishKumarShah's comment was probably about my answer before I edited (back in 2012 :) ).

Answer (score 5):

Without BouncyCastle:

```
PublicKey publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBinary));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet of code worked for me, had to use BouncyCastle though.

```
byte[] keyBytes = key.getEncoded(); // X.509 for public key
SubjectPublicKeyInfo subPkInfo = new SubjectPublicKeyInfo((ASN1Sequence)ASN1Object.fromByteArray(keyBytes));
byte[] rsaformat = subPkInfo.getPublicKey().getDEREncoded();
```

Comment: The `getPublicKey()` is a deprecated function now.

Comment: `new SubjectPublicKeyInfo(..)` is deprecated as well: Use `SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(...)`.

And instead of `getPublicKey()` use `parsePublicKey()`.