# OpenSSL RSA public key digest

Tags: swift, hash, openssl, rsa, asn.1

I'm trying to calculate the hash over a public key on both iOS (Swift) and macOS (terminal & OpenSSL), but both platforms export the key in a slightly different format.

My Swift code extracts the sequence containing both the modulus and exponent (according to Apple this is the PKCS#1 container).

```swift
let export = SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(publicKey, nil)! as Data
let hash = SHA256.hash(data: export)
// SHA256 digest: 57fc8238c609045b7c0b546f58d5f797ebec4e39eff481459edfb67bd850834d
print(hash)
```

Now when I do similar things with the terminal I get a different output.

```sh
openssl rsa -pubin -outform DER | openssl dgst -sha256                             
# writing RSA key
# 0ee9c99ef4ca3316e90dde23925bc9a670fa309d6f4663bb5d42050b5089b086
```

The latter one is cause by OpenSSL wrapping the output in a fuller structured ASN.1 container.

```
SEQUENCE      (ASN.1 container)
  SEQUENCE
    OID       (RSA algorithm)
    NULL
  BITSTRING
    SEQUENCE  (iOS container)   
      INTEGER (Modulus)
      INTEGER (Exponent)
```

How can I use OpenSSL to export the key into only the sequence iOS expects, so the has will be the same for both commands?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783366/how-to-generate-pkcs1-rsa-keys-in-pem-format#comment84926127_16171594

Comment: If you put that in an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: To be honest, as it stands, I think it is a dupe of the linked-to answer. I've asked Dave to answer there, but I might do if he doesn't. Or I could edit the most upvoted answer so it is at least correct, because currently it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out OpenSSL has an undocumented parameter `-RSAPublicKey_out` that outputs the same data that `SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation` does.

```sh
openssl rsa -pubin -RSAPublicKey_out -outform DER | openssl dgst -sha256
```

This provides the same digest for both iOS and macOS