# Convert Java PrivateKey (PKCS#8 format) to SSH(RSA/DSA) or SSH2

Tags: java, ssh

I have an issue trying to convert a PrivateKey (java.security.PrivateKey) to OpenSSH or SSH.com runtime (or Putty/ppk, if that's possible).
I'm working with a keystore, which only supports PKCS#12 and PKCS#8.

I know the conversion can be done using openssl, but I need to do it runtime (if it's possible).

### If I print my privateKey it looks something like this:

```
RSA private key (2048 bits):                              
modulus: ce02bd801015dd30e31eb59353ffdf8021ce2476557720b69
public exponent: 25                                       
private exponent: 10b41d33e5a0e86bbf635ad4981baa567f4810cb
primeP: f6e3b8fe768e496a31b66fe94339f3011b9c6ec93899e3e932
primeQ: d59cd98d9ecb5506c4bbd9f816b7d9b8913fbfdb108fe6c1aa
primeExponentP: 5012812fef1963eb170abc83010be01c08f476f527
primeExponentQ: 33f5b860b7ec451d5272e1fe135d271f0e92f750f6
crt_coefficient: 876c2a73d1198bd65484c00e74d39bc65ceba5ec6
```

---

Any help is appreciated.

Best regards...
Peter

Comment: you can use java `Bouncy Castle` Cryptographic api to generate keys in runtime.https://www.bouncycastle.org/

Comment: similer question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611383/generating-rsa-keys-in-pkcs1-format-in-java